# Create JSON Array using Java EE 7

Tags: java, json

I am trying to create an JSON Array using Java EE 7 libraries.

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

jsonregistration=(JsonArray) Json.createArrayBuilder()
   .add("APA91bE58Q")
   .add("APA91bGT_sd")
   .build();
```

Works perfectly fine
Assuming i have tons of create the list and it is read from database. When i tried to iterate the code, it doesn't work.

```
jsonregistration=(JsonArray) Json.createArrayBuilder();
while(rs.next())
{
    jsonregistration.add(rs.getString(1));
}
jsonregistration.build();
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? it doesn't add any thing to array? if so might be your resultset don't have anything in it to add.

Comment: No my resultset returns a value. just that when  jsonregistration.add(rs.getString(1)); it returns an error no suitable method found for add(String)
    method Collection.add(JsonValue) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to JsonValue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Json.createArrayBuilder()` returns an object of type `JSONArrayBuilder` so you have to write your code like this and it will work

```
JsonArrayBuilder jsonregistration= Json.createArrayBuilder();
while(rs.next())
{
    jsonregistration.add(rs.getString(1));
}
JsonArray jsonArray =  jsonregistration.build();
```